# ModX PHP page keeps showing cached version of Vimeo API data

Tags: php, caching, vimeo, modx, vimeo-api

I've got this webpage

http://wheelhousenyc.com/page?a=2932612,2932615,2932618,2932620

which is dynamically generated in ModX using a snippet which calls the Vimeo Simple API.

It pulls a list of album & video info. I recently edited the info on Vimeo, but my page won't update.

I tried

- clearing cache from modx manager
- setting 'clear cache on save' for the page
- setting 'clear cache on save' for the snippet
- clearing my browser cache
- loading page from another machine

Nothing works!

And a direct call to the API URI at

http://vimeo.com/api/v2/album/2932612/videos.xml

**does** return the correct new data.

Furthermore, a different page on the site, which uses the Vimeo Advanced API, also returns the correct info. I could switch this problem page to use the advanced, but that would take a lot of work and it doesn't require it.

What's going on?

Comment: Your snippet call is cached, or not?

Comment: I'm not familiar with modx, but the Vimeo Simple API provides various HTTP Caching headers, such as last-modified, and Cache Control max-age. There might be some weird interactions going on there.